# How to offset points from a coastline

Tags: qgis, buffer, offset

I need to create a set of points with a fixed spacing and given distance from a  a georeferenced coastline. My idea is trying to obtain a parallel line and then placing points on it. 
To do the first I tried using the `Offset lines` tool, but the processing gets stuck/really slow: apparently it's because of the small distance I need to set and the complex geometry of the coastline.

Is there any faster way to do this?

Comment: What if you smoothed the coastline first and then ran the same process. This should simplify the coastline geometry?

Comment: I've already tried, I launched the processing on a smoothed coastline and still gets stuck. I'm a bit worried about computing time since I have to repeat this with a set of distances... As for smoothing, I'm using SAGA's 'Line smoothing' tool (found it somewhat more effective than the QGIS one), still can't get rid of some recesses/harbors though. What should I do?

Comment: Smoothing actually adds vertices - you probably want to run "simplify" instead.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick! I didn't know that function.